# QLabel disrupting the center alignment of the layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QVBoxLayout` on the main window which is centered horizontally, and in the layout I added a label that has a `AlignCenter` alignment and a custom `QFrame`. When the size of the label is smaller than the custom frame (the English box), everything works as intended:

[image]

However, when the size of the label is bigger than the custom frame, the custom frame gets shifted to the left:

[image]

**Why is this happening and how do I fix it?**

Here is an MCVE:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QLabel, QSizePolicy, \
    QStackedLayout, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

app = QApplication([])

main_window = QWidget()
main_window.setMinimumSize(1280, 720)

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)
main_window.setLayout(layout)

label = QLabel()
label.setText("Select Language")
label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 40))
layout.addWidget(label)

class Button(QFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        stacked_layout = QStackedLayout()

        button = QWidget()
        button_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        text = QLabel()
        text.setText("English")
        text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        button_layout.addWidget(text)
        button_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        button.setLayout(button_layout)

        stacked_layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(stacked_layout)

        self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.setFixedSize(260, 320)

layout.addSpacing(40)
layout.addWidget(Button())

main_window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setAlignment()` function you're using only sets the alignment for the *layout*, not its contents.

If you are using a widget that has a maximum size and want to specify an alignment, that has to be declared explicitly:

```
layout.addWidget(Button(), alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Otherwise the widget will try to use all the available space, but since in your case that space is more than it requires, it will use the default system alignment (left, top).

Comment: Thanks! By the way where is this behaviour documented in the documentation?

Comment: It's in the `addWidget()` documentation of each layout type: "The default alignment is 0, which means that the widget fills the entire cell."; which means that if you don't speficy an alignment *but* the widget has a width/height less than the available size, it will use the "local" default "layout direction" (as in "reading"): always on top, on the left for left-to-right systems and viceversa.

Comment: Note: This is not actually the proper way to center all that stuff as using Qt.AlignCenter all over the place is just way more than is needed and not at all how these objects were designed to be used. If you had used the QHBoxLayouts and QVBoxLayouts with addQStretch(1) properly this could all have been done without using a single Qt.AlignCenter anywhere for anything -- and the ending code is much simpler and a lot cleaner

Comment: @DennisJensen No. The layout is a VBoxLayout, and the problem is getting an horizontal centering with a fixed width widget, this has nothing to do with stretches.

Comment: No @musicamante you are incorrect as it all depends on how you implement the layouts basically -- one should have put the Top QLabel in a HBox -- the QFrame which contains a Label is also placed within an HBox then the two HBox are placed within a VBox -- the Label within the QFrame is placed within an HBox then within a VBox -- this allows dynamic center of the objects in the simplest manner possible no matter what you do with with that window size wise.  BTW did you miss my comment above that states I have already done this in this way?

Comment: @DennisJensen Your method of HBoxes does work out nicely too

Comment: @DennisJensen I know very well what you mean, and I was exactly explaining how it works with a single QVBoxLayout for two simple widgets, for which it really doesn't make any sense to use 5 nested layouts when you can just use the correct QAlignment as soon as you know the size properties of the widgets. If you want to suggest another approach, don't contradict an answer that correctly replies to the question, just make another answer, or at least suggest that *that* is *your* opinion.

Comment: Okay you can call it opinion if you like but the proof is in the pudding drilling down to adjusting the contents of a box versus simply adjusting the placement of the box violates as I said the K.I.S.S. rule so sure if you really want to make things unnecessarily complex that is a choice I suppose and I did not say it was wrong I said not proper aka -- you can get things to a lot of things in many different ways but the proper way is the simplest and most straight forward method as it is always the best solution within programmer and yet folks sometimes do choose the less then optimal solution